# Redrawing graph, jpPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm trying to make a graph that produces random lines and keeps redrawing every 5 seconds. It does redraw but the old scales are overlapped. Is there a way to remove the old graphs before redrawing new graphs?

HTML

```
<div id="pointg"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var k=0;//if graph() is first time

function graph(){   
    var ga=[];
    for(var j=0;j<11;j++){
        ga[j] = Math.random() *20;
    }
        $(function () {
    $.jqplot('pointg', [[[0, ga[0]], [2, ga[1]], [4, ga[2]], [6, ga[3]], [8, ga[4]],[10, ga[5]],[12, ga[6]],[14, ga[7]],[16, ga[8]],[18, ga[9]],[20, ga[10]],[22, ga[11]] ]],{
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                ticks: [ '0', '5', '10', '15', '20' ],
            },
            yaxis: {
                ticks: [ '0', '5', '10', '15', '20' ],
            }
        },
        animate: true,
        seriesDefaults: {
                color: '#ffffff',
                markerOptions: {
                    size: 6
                }

        },
        grid: {
            background: '#000000'
        },
    });
});
    if(k!=0){       
    //remove?   
    }
k++;
;}

graph();
setInterval('graph()',5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that the axis tick labels are drawn on top of each other like this?
[image]

You can use the [destroy()](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.destroy) method to destroy the existing plot before drawing another one. To do this, you'll need to assign your jqplot to a global variable:

```
var plot;

function graph(){
    ...  
    plot = $.jqplot('pointg', [...],{
        axes: {
            ...
        },
        animate: true,
        seriesDefaults: {
            ...
        },
        grid: {
            ...
        },
    });
```

and before you call the $.jqplot(...), ensure you check and destroy the existing plot:

```
if (plot) {
    plot.destroy();
}
```

A full example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dy33ea54/23/). It will result in the following where the axis tick labels are not rendered on top of each other:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted!!